# "bad mirror archive" : What should I put as the "mirror of ubuntu archive" on installation of ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, mirrors

I'm trying to set up ubuntu from my old macintosh laptop, but when it asks me to put in the "mirror of ubuntu archive" I run into problems.

For the mirror, I put in `mirror.anl.gov`
for the ubuntu archive mirror directory, i put in `pub/ubuntu/`
Then I leave the http proxy blank and hit "continue"

It then tries to "download release files", which starts at 0%, and eventually jumps straight to 100% and then it presents me with an error of "bad mirror archive".

Any advice?  I never set up ubuntu before, and I'm really struggling with this step.

Comment: The mirror seems to be up, and the directory seems to be good too. Are you sure about the proxy settings? What about the IP configuration?

Answer (score 2):

How old is this Mac? PowerPC hasn't been on most mirrors since 6.04, so you'll need to find somewhere that's specifically mirroring ports.ubuntu.com