# Bad archive mirror using PXE boot method

Tags: system-installation, automation, pxe, kickstart

I'm trying to automatically install Ubuntu on a client PC by using the **PXE BOOT** method....my Objectives are below:

I am following the steps given in this link [installation using PXE BOOT](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-pxe-install-server-on-ubuntu-9.10)

1. the server will have a KICKSTART
   config file which contains the
   parameters for the OS installation
   and the files which are required for
   the OS installations.
2. the client will have to detect this
   configuration along with the setup
   files and complete the installation
   without any input from the user.

In my server I have installed DHCP3-server,Apache2 and TFTP to help me with the installation.

I have nearly achieved my first objective, I am able to boot my client using the files stored in the server but during the installation stage it is asking me to

`CHOOSE A MIRROR OF UBUNTU ARCHIVE`

I gave the server's IP address and the path in the server where the files are located but then its giving me this error

`BAD ARCHIVE MIRROR`

- So is it possible that instead of
  downloading all the files from the
  internet and storing them on my disk
  can I use the files which comes with
  the UBUNTU-CD, and how to store these
  files in what format (should I zip
  them) on the disk?
- secondly I am also generating the
  ks.cfg which I wanted to give to the
  client for automatic installation of
  the OS. So how should the
  configuration file be given to the
  installation process?

Comment: The first part of your question is a dupe of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28349/bad-mirror-archive-what-should-i-put-as-the-mirror-of-ubuntu-archive-on-ins You might want to split up your questions into individual ones so that we can answer them better instead of all in one question.

Comment: Are you already preseeding via kickstart?  If so, please can you post your .ks file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can save your mirror information in your kickstart file:

```
curl --url http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu
```

You can specify the kickstarter file in the PXE boot line:

```
append vga=normal initrd=installers/jaunty/i386/initrd.gz ks=http://192.168.1.1/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth0 --
```

You should use `apt-mirror` to create a local copy of the ubuntu mirror. It is about 40GB and will take all night to generate. Please see questions directly about each of these things for further details.

Answer (score 0):

check the nodes preseed_master:
got down the file and find APT ,it must looks like :

## APT

d-i     mirror/country string manual

d-i     mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com

d-i     mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu

d-i     mirror/http/proxy string 'your poroxy'

Answer (score 0):

For Focal Fossa (20.04), you can use the following commands in your `kikstart.cfg` file:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string http://archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/codename string focal
```

The `proxy string` line means that it should preserve spaces in URLs.